# BodyFrameReader.AcquireLatestFrame always returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm using the Kinect (v2) plugin for Unity (5.0) to animate a body. I'm using the code below, but `BodyFrameReader.AcquireLatestFrame()` always returns `null`:

```
private KinectSensor _sensor;
private BodyFrameReader _reader;

void Start()
{
    _sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

    if (_sensor != null)
    {
        _reader = _sensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();

        if (!_sensor.IsOpen)
        {
            _sensor.Open();
        }
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (_reader != null)
    {
        var frame = _reader.AcquireLatestFrame(); //This always returns null

        if (frame == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("No frame available");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I did some debugging, and I can see that I get one frame, and after that `AcquireLatestFrame()` is always null. In `BodyFrameReader.cs` it calls the native method `Windows_Kinect_BodyFrameReader_AcquireLastestFrame(_pnative)`. Which returns the `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a suspicion of what went wrong. The first time I ran the program, I probably forgot to Dispose the frame. Since I'm working in Unity, no new process is started when starting a debugging session. Thus I suspect Unity was holding on to that frame.

When copy pasting the code to a new project, the main Unity process had to be restarted (in the process dropping the frame). Had I simply closed and restarted Unity, the problem would have gone away by itself.

Comment: This lead me to fix the problem on my application. After an exception occured I didn't dispose the frame in a catch/finally clause (only in the try statement) and all subsequent frames requests failed.

Answer (score 2):

if you have one image then nothing it means you haven't released resources and it can't overwrite on it. 
At the end of your update you have to release all resources you used (except your reader I guess)
it's easy to release pointers in C++, though I don't know how to do in c#.
If I was you i would look in the samples to find where they release resources.

Comment: In the end, I opened a new project, *copy pasted* my code, and it worked.